# delete_part deletes the top border when outputting pdf

Tags: flextable

I am using the following rmarkdown code, using `xelatex` engine:

````
access <- function(x, ...) {
  x <- delete_part(x)
  x <- colformat_double(x, big.mark = "'", decimal.mark = ",")
  x <- set_table_properties(x, layout = "autofit")
  x <- border_remove(x)
  std_border <- fp_border_default(width = 1, color = "black")
  x <- border_outer(x, part="all", border = std_border )
  x <- border_inner_h(x, border = std_border, part="all")
  x <- border_inner_v(x, border = std_border, part="all")
  autofit(x)
}

firstc <- c("Field:","Table:","Sort:","Show:","Criteria:","Or:")
secondc <- c("Field:","Table:","Sort:","Show:","Criteria:","Or:")
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
tabela <- data.frame(firstc,secondc)
ft <- flextable(tabela)
ft <- access(ft)
ft <- hline_top(ft)

ft <- fit_to_width(ft, max_width = 4)
ft <- set_table_properties(ft, layout = "autofit", width = 1)
ft
```
````

However, the top hline does not show up in the PDF output.

Any ideas?

Comment: you found a bug! I'll add that in the issues of flextable

Comment: Thanks, David! Is there some workaround to use while awaiting until you fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think - it's a bug with only latex

Comment: So, there is no way to remove the headers of a flextable while keeping the border, David?

Comment: Well, a dirty solution is to use as headers the first row of the table -- it works until the issue is fixed.